# Remove columns with standard deviation of zero

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove all columns with a standard deviation of zero from a data.frame.

This does not work:

```
  df <- df[, ! apply(df , 2 , function(x) sd(x)==0 ) ]
```

I get error:

> undefined columns selected

**UPDATE**

I selected `Filter` as my preferred answer as it also seems to handle `NA`s, which is very useful.

For example, in

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c(0,0,NA,0,0), v2=1:5)
```

the column 'v1' is removed with `Filter` while the `apply` methods produce errors.

Thanks to all the other solutions, I learned a lot from them.

**UPDATE2:**

Those errors given by apply can be fixed by adding `na.rm = TRUE` to the call to sd like so:

```
df[, ! apply(df , 2 , function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)==0 ) ]
```

Comment: your code actually works for me???

Comment: @grrgrrbla yes, on a trivial example it works, but on my actual data frame only your `Filter` solution seems to work.

Comment: It worked for me too using the example in my post , a compact version is  `df[apply(df, 2, sd)!=0]`

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example (possibly using `dput` output) that won't work with your code?

Comment: I would be careful here, the reason why your code doesnt work could be that the columns in your data.frame are not numeric or something of the sort, so check why your original code didnt work

Comment: @grrgrrbla To add, if the the OP have columns of 'character' class, then `Filter` with `sd` won't work as well.

Comment: yeah I thought so, so I am confused as to why Filter works and apply won't work

Comment: If there are only 'factor' and 'numeric', then I guess the `sd` will coerce the `factor` to `numeric` and get a FALSE for only a single unique element.  But, in the case of `apply`, any non-numeric element will coerce the whole output to a matrix of 'character' class.  (not tested)

Comment: one more reason to always check if the types of your input match the required input for your function! @OP you could just adapt your code with `sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)` and it will work fine like Filter does

Comment: If there are NA's, you need to use `na.rm=TRUE` ie. `df[apply(df, 2, sd, na.rm=TRUE)!=0]`

Comment: I edited that into the OP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use filter:

```
Filter(function(x) sd(x) != 0, df)
```

Comment: Very useful and practical. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @grrgrrbla 's and @akrun 's answer using `Filter`, here is the correct way to do what you originally had in mind:

```
df <- df[, !sapply(df, function(x) { sd(x) == 0} )]
```

**Or**

```
df <- df[, sapply(df, function(x) { sd(x) != 0} )]
```

I used `sapply()` to get a vector which is `TRUE` when a data frame column have a standard deviation of 0 and `FALSE` otherwise.  Then I subset the original data frame using this vector.

Comment: I think I need a ! before sapply if want these removed?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use `Filter` without anonymous function call as a 'SD' of '0' gets coerced to 'FALSE' and everything else to 'TRUE' to `Filter` out only the columns that are `TRUE` or `sd!=0`

```
 Filter(sd, df)
```

Or if there are columns with mixed class, `length(unique)` might be more general.

```
 df[vapply(df, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x)))>1, logical(1L))]
```

---

Or we can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df %>% 
   map_lgl(~sd(.) !=0) %>%
   extract(df, .)
```

#### data

```
 df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 4, 2, 5), V2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2), V3 = c(3, 
  4, 3, 3), V4 = c(1, 2, 3, 3)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4"
  ), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: clever, because 0 gets coerced to FALSE and everything else gets coerced to TRUE right, because Filter coerces to logical?

Comment: I would include that as the explanation inside your post, because this might not be obvious to most people reading this (who are probably beginners)